# Need APK file downloaded while installing APP

Tags: android, apk

I need the APK file which downloaded during app installation from google play. I am unable to find it in the download folder. Is it possible to get it from download?

Comment: I may need the same thing, but I'm guessing the app will need to start and download it itself. What's your use case?

Comment: Moreover, what does this have to do with Android application development?

Comment: it downloaded automatically and install it on mobile but i need the apk cuz i want to save it to my computer.

Comment: What has this got to do with programming for Android?

Comment: some people dnt have access to internet that why i need to install apps manually on their mobile.

Comment: As stated at the top of the home page for the android tag on stackoverflow, `For non-developer questions, see http://android.stackexchange.com.` Users there will likely have more experience with non-development Android questions.

Comment: belongs on android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Not really. If you've downloaded it from the Android store, it will definitely not show you the apk. This is so people can't just send the apk of a paid app to oneanother.

Answer (score 2):

Try with utility apps like "rom toolbox" for example, you can make backup apps in your phone in apk, there's a lot of apps that can do it anyway, but most probably you'll need root access.

Answer (score 0):

try with Airdroid, awesome... you can transfer any data from your phone to computer and inverse through your wi-fi conection, i love it! ;-)

Comment: what does Airdroid do .?

Comment: Err, `you can transfer any data from your phone to computer and inverse through your wi-fi conection`

Comment: You can sync your phone to computer to make backups of your apps, photos, music, contact list... basically you can transfer all your phone data to computer, you just only need a wifi connection to work: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=es